# Exit code of Java not coming in Bash

Tags: java, bash

I have a bash file:

```
REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"

SVNLOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook
LOGMSG=$($SVNLOOK log -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | grep "[a-zA-Z0-9]")

echo "\n$LOGMSG" >> /dev/tty

javac ~/Desktop/SomeClass.java
java ~/Desktop/SomeClass $LOGMSG

STATUS=$? 
echo "\n" >> /dev/tty
echo $STATUS >> /dev/tty

exit 0
```

which calls this java file:

```
public class SomeClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result = "";
        for (String s: args) {
            result = result + " " + s;

        }

       String regex = ".*\\bHello\\b.*";

       if(result.matches(regex)) {
           System.out.println("It matches");
           System.exit(0);
       } else {
           System.out.println("It does not match");
           System.exit(42);
       }
    }
}
```

I have never in the Java file have exited with the exit code of `1`. However when I echo the status in the bash file, it always shows me '1' What can be the reason behind this?

Comment: Pretty sure that `Someclass` is a typo (little C); also, that's not the way you specify a class to Java (you need the fully-qualified *class name*, not path; and maybe a classpath).

Comment: It works fine for me! I get the exit code 42 in my shell....

Comment: It isn't for me that's the issue

Comment: @AndyTurner can you clarify on it a bit more please. I'm still getiing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code is because Java is failing to start. You aren't specifying the class to be run correctly.

If I have a class located in my desktop directory, I would need to use the following to run it from another directory:

```
java -cp ~/Desktop SomeClass
```

assuming that `SomeClass` has no package specified. If you have `package org.foo.bar;` at the top of the file, you would need to use

```
java -cp ~/Desktop org.foo.bar.SomeClass
```